# Why are these differences not significant (Mann-Whitney U test)?

Tags: statistical-significance, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

For my academical research, I have generated eight Twitter bots. Each bot is specialized in one subject. I have four subjects and two genders (a bot can be either male or female), and each bot has a unique subject-gender combination. So you might have a male bot that's specialized in cars.

The table below shows how many followers each bot managed to gather. So, for example, the male bot with subject 1 had 692 followers. Now, I am curious whether there's a significant difference between the number of followers that the male bots gathered, versus the ones that females managed to gather.

```
Subject     | Female | Male
1           | 692    | 408
2           | 504    | 456
3           | 211    | 175
4           | 210    | 162
```

As you can see, there's quite a big difference between the number of followers from male and female bots - the female score is consistently higher for each subject. Since the differences are quite large for three of the four subject, I don't understand why the Mann-Whitney U test states that the differences are not significant (since p=0.1562).

Could someone please explain this to me? Or am I using the wrong test in this scenario?

Comment: Your wording suggests that these are paired data in which case you have the wrong test altogether.

Comment: @mdewey I have improved the description of my experiment, hopefully this will clear things up.

Comment: Yeah definitely looks paired on subject, so not Mann Whitney. But with only 4 pairs you'll have little hope of significance with any nonparametric test; your smallest possible two tailed p-value will be 0.125.

Comment: @Glen_b What test should I use then? The data is non parametric and we're dealing with two independent groups, right?

Comment: "nonparametric" is an adjective applied to methods of inference or sometimes to models, but not to data. These appear to be counts, why would you not use a parametric model that should be suitable for count data? ... to me it sounds like what you're trying to do is compare proportions within each subject. There might be a reasonable way to compare them via say logistic regression (binomial glm), for example, or perhaps a Poisson regression (among other possibilities)..

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you for your explanation. If I understand your explanation right, the independent samples t-test would be correct to use in this scenario. However, that test also points to a non-significant difference. Would a one-way chi-square test be correct here?

Comment: What about, say, a negative binomial regression (or Poisson, but Poisson seems to hardly ever be quite right) with factors for gender and topic, given that these are count outcomes? I suppose one might also wonder whether the effect of gender differs by topic (but I guess there's hardly enough data), not that there's necessarily enough data here to do that.

Comment: @Björn Thanks for your suggestion, but I'm afraid this goes a little over my head. How would I ever be able to use negative binomial regression to determine whether the groups no. of followers significantly differ? I can't seem to find anything about a p value or the like.

Comment: "the independent samples t-test" would NOT be correct to use in this scenario. 1. The values within subject would be paired not independent (I have stated you have pairing already); 2. the assumption of constant variance is almost certainly violated by the fact that you have counts with apparently varying mean. You could avoid the first issue by doing a paired t-test but not the second.